# Flutter: open_file package does nothing

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter application. I've been using the `open_file` package for quite a while now to open files, but suddenly it doesn't work. I tried altering the code to print out the result of `envokeMethod`, and this is what shows up in the terminal.

```
I/flutter (13494): Result: {"type":-3,"message":"Permission denied: android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}
```

I tried adding the permission `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in `AndroidManifest.xml` but it didn't work. I checked my app permission, it has access to file and media.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried downgrading your package and trying?

Comment: I did, but it didn't work, I also tried a branch package called open_filex, didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

After looking for some stuffs, I finally found the problem. When I checked my app's permission, for some reason there are only 2 options in File and Media section, which are Media only and Deny. For some reason file isn't included there, so I looked it up and found out that you need a specific permission starting from Android 11, which is called manageExternalStorage. So I had to ask for storage permission, then manageExternalStorage permission, and only then I could see a third option in the File and Media permission, which is All Files. After applying and asking for that permission, open_file works perfectly fine. BUT, it turns out that ManageExternalPermission is a pretty sensitive permission, which in my case, my application doesn't fulfill the requirement to ask for that permission, and was rejected due to that when I published it to Play Store. So I ended up forking the open_file package, changed it so that it doesn't require ManageExternalStorage permission, and it all works fine after that.

Comment: Hi, can you show the code for manageExternalStorage? I am facing quite similar problem. I can open images but cannot install .apk file, and in permission, only allow media. So I think that might also be the problem for my app

Comment: Hi, sorry I just read this, turns out this isn't exactly the answer if you're trying to publish your application. ManageExternalStorage is a pretty sensitive permission, which can only be requested if your application fulfill the requirements. I ended up forking the open_file package, and make some changes directly on the code so that it won't ask for ManageExternalPermission, since my application doesn't need to do so. You can check it here https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/issues/219